# SQLAlchemy: Can't adapt type 'dict'

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a flask app, and try to store an object in a Postgres DB using SQLAlchemy.
I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type
'dict' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO events (organizer_id, name, date, _address,
_polygon, starter_time, main_time, dessert_time, afterparty_flag,
afterparty_address, afterparty_description) VALUES (%(organizer_id)s, %
(name)s, %(date)s, %(_address)s, %(_polygon)s, %(starter_time)s, %
(main_time)s, %(dessert_time)s, %(afterparty_flag)s, %(afterparty_address)s, %
(afterparty_description)s) RETURNING events.id'] [parameters: {'organizer_id':
 7, 'name': 'testevent', 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 27, 19, 8, 38,
 90484), '_address': None, '_polygon': {}, 'starter_time':
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 27, 19, 8, 38, 90500), 'main_time':
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 27, 19, 8, 38, 90508), 'dessert_time':
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 27, 19, 8, 38, 90514), 'afterparty_flag': True,
'afterparty_address': None, 'afterparty_description': None}]
```

My Event model:

```
class Event(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'events'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
organizer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organizers.id'))

# general
name = db.Column(db.String(64))
date = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
_address = db.Column(db.Text(), default={})
_polygon = db.Column(db.Text(), default={})

# timetable
starter_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
main_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
dessert_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)

# afterparty
afterparty_flag = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True)
afterparty_address = db.Column(db.String(140))
afterparty_description = db.Column(db.String(140))

postcode = None
city = None
```

There is an organizer with the id: 7 in my database.
I already spent hours reading the logs and experimenting.

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Your `_polygon` column specifies a type of `Text` but has a default value of `{}`, which is a `dict`.

Comment: @Jan: you can (and probably should in this case) [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if no one has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change of the following two lines fixed the error.

```
_address = db.Column(db.Text(), default={})
_polygon = db.Column(db.Text(), default={})


_address = db.Column(db.Text(), default="")
_polygon = db.Column(db.Text(), default="")
```